# Is the null always thrown on the topmost line mentioned in the trace?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to locate the source of the error in this trace:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException: Handler execution resulted in exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.wikistart.service.WikiServiceImpl.getWikis(WikiServiceImpl.java:548)
    at com.wikistart.controller.WikiController.wiki(WikiController.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
```

Is the null always thrown on the topmost line mentioned in the trace?

In other words, this `NullPointerException` is coming from `WikiServiceImpl.java:548` and not from `WikiController.java:88`?

Comment: While the exception happened there, sometimes (usually) it happened because you passed a null into an API that wasn't expecting one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the top of the trace is where the exception is coming from.  The stack trace is showing you where each method was called from.

So in your case, the NullPointerException was thrown in WikiServiceImpl.java on line 548, and the method that was executing there was called from WikiController.java line 88, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is coming from the topmost line.

From there each line down indicates a method that calls the above. [See here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/) for more information about stacktraces.

Check [the possible reasons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) for a `NullPointerException` - it should then be obvious which object causes the exception.

Comment: That's a difficult question. Especially as a sufficient answer is shorter that the 15 char answer length limit :)

Comment: agreed. That's why I tried to provide some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Stack represents where you were in you were in the code. The call starts are the bottom and works upwards.